# How to stop autogeneration of admin user accounts

Tags: macos, high-sierra, user-account

I have a computer that I use for work and, after installing a bunch of required proprietary software, I noticed that my MacBook Pro (macOS 10.13.2) is auto-generating a new admin user account called "[COMPANY NAME] Admin Support".

I ended up deleting what I thought was all the proprietary software from my company, as it slowed down my computer and in general I had no idea what kinds of things it was running in the background. (For one, I kept getting notifications that not all the required software I needed to install was installed.)

But apparently I didn't get rid of all of it, because no matter how many times I delete this user account, it always pops back up within a matter of a day or two. Where should I look to find the files or processes that are auto-regenerating this user account, and then how do I kill it?

Comment: Is any of that *proprietary software* MDM (mobile device management) software?  You're going to have to provide more details before we can provide an answer.

Comment: I don't believe so, no. And anyway this is just affecting my Mac, not my phone (which doesn't have any corporate software on it). FWIW, I just deleted the admin user about 4 hours ago and it's already reappeared (without my computer restarting).

Comment: MDM isn't limited to phones.  How did you determine there's no MDM software in that proprietary bunch?  Whose computer is it?  Your's or your companies?  Was it enrolled in Apple's management program?

Comment: So the company is Oracle and the software I'd installed (and then quickly uninstalled) is called MyDesktop. I'm not sure what functionality it includes other than that it checks that various apps are installed on your computer.

Comment: Oracle MyDesktop is part of the Secure Global Desktop product (formerly part of the the SunRay Server software) that allows you to have access to a desktop compute session in the cloud that give you access from anywhere via any supported device.  This software doesn't create an Admin account since it doesn't need a separate one.  However, your company may need to administer your device to manage SGD so there is some sort of MDM software running you're probably not aware of.

Comment: Thank you! I'll dig into what else it installed, as it's definitely creating a new admin account every time I delete it.